# "404 Not Found" with a customized url rule in flask

Tags: python, flask

I'm new to Flask. I am frustrated by facing an error when following the tutorial.

When I define a function as

```
@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return 'Hello World!'
```

Then type `http://127.0.0.1:5000` in browser, it works fine. But when I added another route

```
@app.route('/')
@app.route('/abc')
def hello():
    return 'Hello World!'
```

and type `http://127.0.0.1:5000/abc` in browser, it shows "Not Found". My full script is:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/abc')
def hello():
    return 'Hello World!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Do I miss anything? Thanks!

Comment: It is working for me

Comment: When you added another route, did you restart flask?

Comment: Might be and issue with cache. Please try with some other browser or clear the cache.

Comment: when you are running servers (python, java) locally, cache is a very rare issue

Comment: The same code is working for me as well.

Comment: @vincent Enable the debug flag and print some values to check what issue are you getting exactly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201637/discussion-between-shivendra-pratap-kushwaha-and-harshal-parekh).

Comment: @ShivendraPratapKushwaha yes it's indeed a cache issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Might be and issue with cache. Please try with some other browser or clear the cache.